# About naming an App ID in IOS provisioning portal

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am working for an Australian company atm. When I create an Apple ID in "Provisioning Portal", can i just use prefix as "au.com.mycompany.appname" instead of "com.mycompany.appname". Our company do not have a ".com" website. I got questions about:

1. What's different between "com.mycompany.appname" and "au.com.mycompany.appname"
2. Will this cause me any trouble in the future development, like in-app purchase, distribution or push notification service?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  You could even use "somethingWithNoDotAndNotEvenYourCompanyName", as long as it's unique.  The "com.company.product" is only a recommandation.

I myself use "ca.mycompany.product" without any problem.

Comment: can i actually use 1 App ID for different projects?

Comment: Nop. That's the point of unique identifiers, they are unique. You could, however, make small variations if that helps you stay organized! (like au.com.mycompany.globalproject.subproject1, au.com.mycompany.globalproject.subproject2, etc.).

Comment: Well, that confusing me. So, what u mean is, technically i could use same App ID for different projects, but not been suggested to do so. I should use different ids for different projects. Or, i just cannot use it for different projects. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: Ok maybe I wasn't clear:
Let's say you have two apps. One is appA and the other appB.
You CAN use any identifier you want for each app, as long as both identifiers are unique: they can use your australian domain or no domain at all (ex. "appAprojectByMyCompany" and "appBprojectByMyCompany")
It is recommended, though, to use the format "reversedDomain.appname" (so "au.com.mycompany.appA" and "au.com.mycompany.appB").
If the two apps are related (ex.: a lite app and it's full counterpart), you could use "au.com.mycompany.projectx.appA" and "au.com.mycompany.projectx.appB").

Comment: that is a nice reply, thanks so much man for your time on this.

Comment: a new question: i used "au.com.mycompany.somethingnotmyproductname" for my APP ID and why i got Identifier named "au.com.mycompany.myproductname" showing in xcode? do i have to make the APP ID same as Identifier name?

Answer (score 0):

You can use whatever string you want. `au.com.mycompany` is good if you own the domain name, because that (sort of) guarantees no one else will use it. The examples start with `com` but that's certainly not necessary.