# What are all the things an app ID is used for in iOS apps, what is the downside of making it alphanumeric?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, deployment, distribution

We'd like to change the App ID that we currently use without changing the seed ID- we want to change the bundle ID to a GUID. I know that the app bundle ID is used:

1. During installation to check that the distribution profile app ID (Second part) matches the bundle ID in the info.plist. So we have to generate a new provisioning profile.
2. By iTunes to segregate apps and identify upgrades for apps. I guess this means this will come out with iTunes treating it as a new app?

Are there any limitations you foresee with making it alphanumeric? Are there any other changes we will have to make?

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259947/about-naming-an-app-id-in-ios-provisioning-portal)
states that it need not be in reverse domain name convention... can anyone think of why a GUID would be a problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say APP ID, you are really meaning Bundle Identifier. `App ID` in context of an iPhone app means the App Store ID (ex: 29184024). You are not allowed to change the bundle id of an existing app per Apple, so you will have to create a new app from scratch. There are no limitations in making it alphanumeric, but if you create a new Bundle Identifier altogether, your older customers will not get updates.