# iPhone - Changing Bundle identifier : what will happen?

Tags: iphone, app-store, bundle, identifier

What may happen if I change my app bundle identifier ?

For example, if I go from com.myapps.appname to com.myapps.utilities.appname, or com.myapps.appname.appnameFULL

What may happen for people who have already bought the app ?
What may happen with stored datas ?
...

Comment: My recommendation is avoid changing it if you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not be allowed to change it in iTunesConnect so there is no ramification as there is no possible way to do it. If you create a new app with a new bundle id, obviously old users of the other app will not get the updates. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096264/what-are-all-the-things-an-app-id-is-used-for-in-ios-apps-what-is-the-downside-o/7096439#7096439) related question